# how to get the tray icons

Tags: c#

I am making my own taskbar which will replace the default windows one. How do I get a list of everything that is in the system tray (notification area)?

Comment: Hey! I am not the only one doing this!

Answer (score 1):

[FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499(VS.85).aspx) with the classname `Shell_TrayWnd` can get you this information. Here are two sample C++ projects

http://skyscraper.fortunecity.com/gigo/311/winprog/shellico.txt

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/ShellTrayInfo.aspx

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to create an icon in the notification area (usually near the clock in the taskbar), see the [`NotifyIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx) class.  The docs have an example for creating a notification icon with a context menu.

Comment: I think Alex wants to determine what icons are in the system tray

Comment: yes because I want to change my winxp style with my own taskbar by hiding explorer.exe and getting screenshots of the running programs so that is looks really smooth when you do mouseover the sreenshot pops up, and so on. now i want to add more functions by displaying the tray icons...

Comment: You mean you want to write your own version of what Vista and Windows 7 do for use on XP? Seems cheaper and easier to just upgrade.

Comment: thanks for this question. I am aiming just what @alex want : replace explorer as the default shell. Here is another important question regarding those : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081517/any-open-source-alt-tab-windows-switcher-project-exists