# Any open source Alt-Tab windows switcher project exists?

Tags: windows, alt-tab, switchers

Having tried a few Alt-Tab windows switcher, I want to write one to suit my own needs.  Are you aware of any open source Alt-Tab windows switchers?  If it already exists, I don't want to start from scratch :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's source code you're after you may look at TaskSwitchXP sources:
http://www.ntwind.com/software/taskswitchxp/download.html

The same company offers VistaSwitcher, however that one is not open source.

Answer (score 1):

You can try AltTabAlternative : https://alttabalternative.sourceforge.io/

Sources are available at https://github.com/lokeshgovindu/AltTabAlternative

Comment: Great job Lokesh. Prior to trying your app, I tried Easy Window Switcher (was a bit faulty with Alt+` switching), and Vista Switcher (worked on initial install for me, but then always crashed on startup on future runs). Your one is working well, and is a sturdy, viable alternative to the others available, and open-source too!